# how to use libssl.so in an android project?

Tags: android, openssl

I did build the libssl.so from openssl project with Android NDK under the mac os x shell and now I would like someone to tell me how i can use it in Eclispe and in my android project ?

Is it ok if I drag and drop the file in the project root directory ??

How can I access the library function from the code ??

I saw this example :

```
// load the library - name matches jni/Android.mk

  static {
    System.loadLibrary("ndkfoo");
  }

  // declare the native code function - must match ndkfoo.c

  private native String invokeNativeFunction();

...

file ndkfoo.c :
jstring Java_com_mindtherobot_samples_ndkfoo_NdkFooActivity_invokeNativeFunction(JNIEnv* env, jobject javaThis) {
  return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "Hello from native code!");
}
```

But the libssl.so has it own functions list and they not named with my java class name i guess...

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to link .so file to yr project, u need to right click project->properties->Java Build Path->Library->Android 2.* -> Native Library location ->Edit -> browse to .so file folder path

Comment: thanks for the info, I have found what you said. But do you know how Im suppose to use the functions from the lib from android java ? Because this is an openssl lib that i didnt created and I dont see how to use the C functions from it from Android java... Am I suppose to do kind of JNI wrapper files for every functions of the lib ???